# I connected two ends of battery with copper wire, and nothing happened. Why?

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor

I'm trying to build a simple motor with the help of some youtube tutorials but nothing seems to spin... so I figures ok let's connect the ends of the battery and see if that the problem. If I get electrocuted then everything is all right lol. I tried with 2 batteries and nothing happened...
Does someone have an idea what the problem might be? I'm using a 1.5V battery, is that maybe too little?

The wire isn't isolated, so I really have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I hope that's not how you check whether your circuit breaker is working or not.

Comment: Where did you get this "copper wire" from? It could be enameled (insulated). And yes, it's unclear to me what do you expect to happen. It will probably get hot and the battery will die quickly.

Comment: Do you not own a multimeter? They are extremely cheap

Comment: I expected to feel heat or electricity somehow, idk :P

Comment: you need to wait longer while it's shorted. but not too long ;)

Comment: Ok I do everything, I feel the heat but still nothing spins.... How strong does the magnet have to be? I really don't know what else it could be

Answer (score 2):

1.5v isn't enough to "electrocute" you. In fact, it may not even be enough to make a visible spark when you short the battery. (Shorting a battery is, by the way, a Bad Idea. There's a chance of leakage, overheating, all the bad stuff.)

If the battery and the wire didn't get warm during the short, the battery probably wasn't any good to begin with. Even a AA should change noticeably. Maybe there's something wrong with your motor construction? Weak magnets? There are a lot of improvised motor designs. Post a link to the one you're using and maybe some hypotheses can be raised.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bH7DFPIayNg
I tried moving the magnet around also but I get zero response

Comment: Are you certain you adequately removed the enamel from your wire?  It can be hard to see, but it will prevent current from flowing.

Comment: I actually didn't even to that.... Ok that might be the problem.
I thought copper wire conducts as it is

Comment: Magnet wire, such as you would use to wind the coil for a motor, is insulated with a thin tough enamel coating.  At first glance, it may appear to be bare copper.  You need to remove the enamel to make contact with the actual copper conductor.

Comment: Is it possible to overdo it? Because I removed it everywhere and it still won't spin

Comment: You should only remove the enamel where you want to make connections.  If you remove the enamel on that part of the wire in a coil, the turns of the coil will short-circuit, and the coil will not behave as you require.